# How to replace a character from a variable location of a string up to the last character

Tags: regex, find-and-replace

Question, please:

How do I remove characters starting with _ then all the way to the end.  Examples are:

- `FC1-46-SCD-02-008-11_14P` will be `FC1-46-SCD-02-008-11`
- `FC1-46-SCD-02-0008-11D_0P` will be `FC1-46-SCD-02-008-11D`

Please note that `_` is not properly at fixed location.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Backspace?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: OS and/or application would be useful.  If you're limited to a single _, then `cut` from the linux command line would work well, any regex supporting editor would do this, a spreadsheet if you select _ as the delimiter, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the items into **Notepad++**, one per line, You can do a find and replace with `_.*`.
The `_` is the character you are looking for and `.*` tells it to select any characters after that to the end of the line. Leave the replace field blank to replace it with nothing.

[image]

Comment: If you’re on a Unix-like system, or have access to Unix-like tools, you can do the same with `sed`, like this: `sed "s/_.*//"`.

Comment: @Scott `cut` is probably easier in this case . . . I think `cut -d_ -f1 <filename>`?

Comment: @Vitie please mark the answer